# Mac MySQL data folder access denied

Tags: macos

My MySQL data directory is located at `/usr/local/mysql/data`
When I view it in finder I get this:

[image: Finder Screenshot]

When I try to open the data folder I get an *access denied* error.

Via the terminal I can execute the command `sudo cd /usr/local/mysql/data` without errors, yet I don't enter the data directory. `ls` gives back the contents of my root dir.

The same bevahiour occurs with the command `sudo cd /usr/local/mysql/data/firma` ("firma" is a existing database name)

However when I write some nonsense instead of "firma", it gives me an error, thus I'm in the correct directory. I can also view the file size of said firma directory / file.

*How can I view all the files in the data directory?*

Comment: What have you tried so far to change permissions? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4171806 or https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-folders-have-a-red-minus-symbol.974989/ or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1823050

Comment: Could solve it by chaning the permissions. In hindsight I don't know why I haven't thought of this myself haha. Thanks a lot!